# Replace Find-AzureRmResource with Get-AzureRmResource in AzureRM for Tagging Resources

Tags: azure, powershell

I have a script that will apply all tags in a resource group to the child resources in the group. The script uses Find-AzureRmResource which has been depricated and removed from the newest modules. It says it has been replaced with Get-AzureRmResource, however I am unable to get it working properly with replacing with that. I get the error:

"Get-AzureRmResource : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the 
input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input."

Here is the original script that used to work:

```
$rgname = "rg123"

$group = Get-AzureRmResourceGroup $rgname
if ($group.Tags -ne $null) {
$resources = $group | Find-AzureRmResource
foreach ($r in $resources)
{
    $resourcetags = (Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceId $r.ResourceId).Tags
    foreach ($key in $group.Tags.Keys)
    {
        if (($resourcetags) -AND ($resourcetags.ContainsKey($key))) { $resourcetags.Remove($key) }
    }
    $resourcetags += $group.Tags
    Set-AzureRmResource -Tag $resourcetags -ResourceId $r.ResourceId -Force
}
}
```

here is the find-azurermresource I am trying to replace with:

```
$resources = $group | Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName $rgname
```

I have tried variations with -ResourceType as well, but still get the same error that it cannot take pipeline inputs. Is there away to get get this line working again with the replaced cmdlet Get-AzureRmResource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can immediatly use the following, no need to use `Get-AzureRmResourceGroup`:

`$resources = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName $rgname`

This will get all resources from that specific group.

Comment: That fixed it, just replaced the line: $resources = $group | Find-AzureRmResource with your line above.